# global vairable did not initialize correctly between running multiple test cases in c++

Tags: c++

I am still actively learning c++ with a strong background in python3, the point of this question is **not** seeking any help with solving the problem [Decode Variations](https://leetcode.com/problems/decode-ways/) on leetcode or pramp, but to understand the compilation or syntax related issue in c++.

The following code using dfs runs well if I run it case by case, however on pramp, it failed in RUN TESTS! Very surprising! It seems like in test case #2  `int n=0;` was not initialized and used the output of n in test case #1 as its value rather than 0, see the console in the attached screenshot at the end.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int n=0;

void dfs(const string& s, int i){
  if (i==s.size()){
    n++;
    return;
  }
  if ( 0<s[i]-'0' && s[i]-'0'<10)
    dfs(s, i+1);
  if (i+1<s.size() && 10<=stoi(s.substr(i,2)) && stoi(s.substr(i,2))<=26)
    dfs(s, i+2);
}

int decodeVariations(const string& s)
{

  dfs(s,0);
  cout<<n<<endl;
  return n;
}



int main() 
{

    return 0;
}
```

Here is the code to run test case #2:

```
int main() 
{
  const string s = "26";
  dfs(s,0);
  cout<<n<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

If I added another initialization of `n=0;` to `int decodeVariations(const string& s)`, then everything works fine. I try to become a programmer with a clear mind, please educate me.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Don't use a global. Figure out a way for `dfs` to return the value you seek.

Comment: @WhozCraig we definitely can do that, for example, put ````n```` as a argument in ````dfs(...)````, but I want to know where has gone wrong here.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly. However, the initialization of `n`, `int n = 0;` executes just once, on the first program run. `n` is a global, and you are not setting it anywhere besides the global scope. `n` being a global retains its value between later function calls.

Comment: @stateMachine How are tests run by the c++ code? Compile -> run a test cast -> compile -> run a test cast -> ... so much so. I don't understand this process in c++. Or compile  -> run test cast 1 -> run a test cast 2  -> run a test cast 3 ...

Comment: @AlbertGLieu yeah, you could do that. I'd use that return result (currently `void`) myself, but to each their own. In any case, *"It seems like in test case #2 int n=0; was not initialized and used the output of n in test case #1 as its value rather than 0"* is nonsense if the *program* for each test case is different. If the *same* code in the *same* program run instance is stacked into multiple invokes for multiple test cases, obviously that global is a huge problem.

Comment: @stateMachine I believe maybe in Python3, it will "recompile" the code for every test case.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, [non-const global variable is evil](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/why-non-const-global-variables-are-evil/). Even though I don't know how leetcode and pramp (especially, the main function is empty) run a number of test cases, but I get a hunch it runs test case in the main function, which only compile and run the code once. Thus the global did not get reinitialized.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int n=0;

void dfs(const string& s, int i){
    if (i==s.size()){
        n++;
        return;
    }
    if ( 0<s[i]-'0' && s[i]-'0'<10)
        dfs(s, i+1);
    if (i+1<s.size() && 10<=stoi(s.substr(i,2)) && stoi(s.substr(i,2))<=26)
        dfs(s, i+2);
}

int decodeVariations(const string& s)
{

    dfs(s,0);
    return n;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    for (int i=1;i<argc;i++)
        cout<<decodeVariations(argv[i])<<endl;
}
```

run with `./test 26 26 26`
output:

```
2 

4 

6
```

Quick fix is to get rid of global variable

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

//int n=0;
int dfs(const string& s, int i){
  int ans = 0;
  if (i==s.size()){
    return 1;
  }
  if ( 0<s[i]-'0' && s[i]-'0'<10)
     ans += dfs(s, i+1);
  if (i+1<s.size() && 10<=stoi(s.substr(i,2)) && stoi(s.substr(i,2))<=26)
     ans += dfs(s, i+2);
  return ans;
}

int decodeVariations(const string& s)
{
    // your code goes here
  int n;
  n = dfs(s,0);
  cout<<n<<endl;
  return n;
}
```